# Is it possible to read/retrieve a c++ source code from a .sln file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, solution, sln-file

I sent a *.sln* file (instead of *.cpp* file) to a friend; will he be able to read the source code from it or is it just a file used from Visual Studio to load projects?

Comment: A .sln contains no project source. Open it in Notepad and see.

Comment: Short answer: No. The `.sln` file contains only the paths to the containe projects. No source code at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, SLN files only store the project settings. You should send him the whole project in a compressed file.

Just so you know, the recommended way to share code with other people is using a version control system, like [GIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)).

Answer (score 0):

No, a sln file only contains references to your files. So at least he now knows the name of your file ;)